# How to simulate a collection in a model's column Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there any way to keep a collection (list, array or hash) in a model's column so I could make a query like

```
Model.where( collection.include? 'foo')
```

Or is there a way to simulate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes its possible:

```
Model.where(:colname => "#{collection.include?("foo")}")
```

something like this is possible with string interpolation.

Comment: OK, but how do I declare the collection in the model? Is there a column type 'Array' or something?

Comment: you can declare your collection in the model like a normal ruby collection, and if you are asking about database type, then there is no column type like Array.Though you can save multiple value as text.